# What type of value should it be returned by getters that return size of vector?

Tags: c++

What type of value should be returned by getters that return size of vector?

For example I have many getters in my project of the following type and
I need the `(int)` cast to remove the compile warnings:

```
int getNumberOfBuildings() const { return (int)buildings.size(); }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The C++03 way:

```
std::vector<Building>::size_type getNumberOfBuildings() const
{ return buildings.size(); }
```

The C++11 way:

```
auto getNumberOfBuildings() const -> decltype(buildings.size())
{ return buildings.size(); }
```

The C++14 way:

```
auto getNumberOfBuildings() const
{ return buildings.size(); }
```

Comment: I would rather stay with my int conversion rather than any of these :). They are all ugly except the last one but we are not there yet, c++14...

Comment: @user2381422, But `int` causes trouble everywhere. In comparisons, you get warnings, you might get truncation, and you have to do pointless work in the callsite if you want the proper type.

Comment: @chris OK so if you had c++11 which method of the three here would you use?

Comment: @user2381422: Most of the time you are safe returning an `std::size_t`, but *in theory* that is not portable, since the standard does not specify `std::size_t` should be the same as `std::vector<T>::size_type` for any `T`. Also, with GCC 4.8.1 and Clang 3.3 you can use the last form if you compile with the `-std=c++1y` flag

Comment: @user2381422, For whatever reason, I like using `size_type` over `decltype`, but they both give the same thing, so it doesn't matter too much.

Comment: @chris but for both methods I can then get the value with auto correct? auto temp = myObject.getNumberOfBuildings(); In that case things won't be that bad, the ugly stuff will be in the getter.

Comment: @AndyProwl: actually I think the standard does say that `std::allocator<T>::size_type` is `size_t`, and it follows that `std::vector<T>::size_type` is `size_t`. What the standard doesn't say is that `std::vector<T,Alloc>::size_type` is `size_t` for any `Alloc`, so you're right that there can be vectors with other size types.

Comment: @user2381422 For counts I usually just use `unsigned int`, since to me `std::size_t` conceptually feels much more like a size in bytes. Of course everybody will tell you that's not neccessarily the same as `vector::size_type`, but really you're not returning the size of a vector here, you're returning the number of buildings.

Answer (score 5):

You should return a `std::size_t`.  `std::size_t` is the return type of `vector<T>::size()` when you use the default allocator.  `vector<T>::size()` returns `vector<T>::size_type` which is just a typedef for `std::size_t` when you use the default allocator (which you are most likely using).

Comment: Technically, the return type is `vector::size_type`, which is a typedef for the allocator's `size_type`, which in turn is a typedef for `size_t`.  If you have a custom allocator, it might be something different.

Comment: What do you guys mean by default vs custom allocator?

Comment: An allocator is an object that manages how the vector gets memory to store what you put in it.  You can make your own custom allocators, but the default one (`std::allocator`) is good enough in most cases.

Comment: +1 for the one most simple type that will never fail to represent the answer correctly. No matter, how many objects of whatever type you have, you will always be able to count them using size_t, simply because you also have to store them.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector` provides a typedef, `std::vector<>::size_type`, that indicates which is the type used as the result of `vector::size`:

```
std::vector<TYPE>::size_type getNumberOfBuildings() const { return buildings.size(); }
```

This, however, is usually `size_t`, so you can go ahead and use the latter directly:

```
#include <cstddef>

std::size_t getNumberOfBuildings() const { return buildings.size(); }
```

Comment: and then in my code I should also use size_t correct? for example: size_t temp = myObject.getNumberOfBuildings();

Comment: @user2381422 yes. If you're using C++11, you could use the `auto` keyword: `auto temp = myObject.getNumberOfBuildings();`.

Answer (score 3):

The formal answer is indeed `std::vector<Building>::size_type`, as stated in other answers.

The real answer depends on whether you already have a type in your program that you use to represent the number of buildings. It could be `int`, it could be `unsigned` or it could be some typedef name `TBuildingCount`. This is the type you should use in this case. It might require a cast to suppress compiler warnings, but that's the way it usually is.

I don't see the rest of your code, so I can't say it for sure, but I'd guess that the fact that the buildings are stored in some vector somewhere (or in any other container) is just an implementation detail, which should not influence your choice of type for counting these buildings. There's no need to expose the existence of that containber (or rely on it) even in such indirect way as using its `size_type` to return the count.

In other words, if you already decided to use `int` for counting buildings, then the implementation in your question is the one you should stick with.

Comment: I agree with this, but I can't resist quibbling with the last assertion that the questioner "should" stick with a C-style cast. There are alternatives that might be preferable, such as a `static_cast` (to aid certain kinds of code searching) or a `boost::numeric_cast` (to assert the precondition / class invariant that the current value must fit in an `int`).

Answer (score 1):

In contrast to many other answers, the return value of your function actually much more depends on your interface than what you use under the hood. Are you returning the size of a vector and want everybody to know it? Well, then go ahead and use `std::vector::size_type`. But are you actually returning some abstract counting variable, like the number of buildings, then I don't think a `std::vector::size_type` belongs into your interface, since that is just an implementation detail.

If it's a size of something that you return (but not neccessarily known to be a vector under the hood), I'd use good old `std::size_t`, but if it's a count of something, then an `unsigned int` is conceptually much more appropriate. Of course nobody guarantees that an `unsigned int` or `std::size_t` can hold the size of an arbitrary `std::vector`, but then again it's not an arbitrary `std::vector`, it's an array of buildings and you yourself should know if there can ever be more than `std::numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()` buildings anyway.